# Empty tree type in OCaml

Tags: polymorphism, ocaml, variant

I'm trying to create a type representing an empty binary tree (basically, only a skeleton of it). The variables of this type are then meant to be iterated over with pattern matching.

I understand how to instantiate a fixed from polymorphic variant for the standard types (`int`, `string`, etc) - see `int_tree` below. However, it is unclear if it is possible to make an empty variant from polymorphic one (`empty_tree` line below fails with SyntaxError during the compilation process).

The code is as follows:

```
type 'a binary_tree =                                                                                                                
  | Leaf of 'a                                                                                                                       
  | Node of 'a binary_tree * 'a * 'a binary_tree                                                                                     

type int_tree = int binary_tree;;                                                                                                    

type empty_tree = () binary_tree;;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`()` is not a type but it's the only value of the type `unit`.

Writing `() binary_tree` is like writing `0 binary_tree` (instead of `int binary_tree`).

Your empty tree should of type `unit binary_tree`.

Comment: Although that tree would not be empty but contain values of type unit, of which there is only one.

Comment: True, a really empty tree would require a change in the data structure.

Comment: `type +'a tree = Leaf | Node of 'a binary_tree * 'a * 'a binary_tree`

Comment: What does the ``+'a`` means ? That was the modification I was referring to.

Comment: Covariance. It makes the empty tree (Leaf) compatible to any tree type. Just like the empty list ([]) work for any list type. Not sure if it is needed here since the type system usually figures this out on its own.